# Haskell - Is it possible to take 2 ints and find a common exponent?

Tags: haskell, exponential, exponent

Lets say i want to find if the relation between the amount of possible triangles with integer angles and quadrilaterals with integer angles can be represented by an exponent. like say T is triangles and Q is quadrilaterals

```
Q = T^x
```

Is there a function that I can use to find if i can represent it like that and if possible, what the exponent is?

Comment: Neither is this a Haskell question, nor does it IMO qualify as sufficiently researched. If you flesh this out a bit, it might make a good [Math.SE](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com) or perhaps [CS.SE] question though.

Comment: Ah, I ment to be asking if there was a built in function for this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "non-decimal triangle" or "quadrilateral"? Does `x = log Q / log T` work for you?

Comment: Got me again. I ment triangles and quaderlateral shapes with integer angles and i fixed the question to reflect that. My laptop gave out on running the calc on quaderlaterals but im working on another test case. Ill comment the results.

Comment: That worked but apparently there already is a function for that as stated by the answer, but thanks for showing how it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `q = t^x`, then `x = logBase t q`.